# omit child values with jq

Tags: json, linux, key, jq

I've got the following document

```
~/ cat /tmp/stuff2 | jq '.'
{
  "x": {
    "a": {
      "c1": 2,
      "c2": "sss"
    },
    "b": {
      "c1": 3,
      "c2": "sfs",
      "c3": {
        "d1": "aa",
        "d2": 3
      }
    },
    "c": {
      "c1": 5,
      "c2": "ssy"
    },
    "d": {
      "c1": 8,
      "c2": "esy"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to do something like the following:

```
~/ cat /tmp/stuff2 | jq '.x | <1st level|not child>'
{
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
  "d"
}
```

Bu I cannot fin a way to omit the subvalues or child of those indexes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want [`keys`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#keys,keys_unsorted):

```
jq '.x|keys' input.json
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
  "d"
]
```

Comment: Exactly, well next time I guess I'll go deeper in the documentation, now I see it.
Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend to get an overview of all the functions available. there aren't sooo many. You can look up details if you need them.

Comment: Or `keys_unsorted` if you want them in the original order.